# Getting logged in user from .Net Core 3.1 Web API

Tags: unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been struggling with this implementation for months. I had a workaround but it's far from ideal.

I've been struggling to get access to the current logged-in user from within my Web API. Ordinarily, I'd perhaps log in through the client and then authorise through a token. The problem I have, however, is that the client isn't the software that makes the log in request.

The client is written in Unity 3D and is embedded into the site. It shares data with the site via a Web API. Before the user gets access to the client, however, they have to log into the site through a standard .Net Core login system. So, as you can see, there's no way to pass an authentication token to the client. What I'm trying to do is have the Web API respond to requests by accessing only the details of the current logged-in user.

At the moment, I've tried gaining access to user data via HttpContext but in order to do that, I've had to enable Windows Authentication in the project. But now, all calls to the Web API result in a 401 error as the client itself can't send any authentication information.

So, what I need to do is find a way to get current logged in user information inside a Web API where the API doesn't need to receive any tokens or other information to do it.

Any ideas how that might be possible?

Comment: You can't get authentication token when login failed. And that's why you got 401(Unauthorized) error when call Web APIs.

Comment: Why can not pass an authentication token to the client?

Comment: I can't pass it because the client doesn't actually perform the login. The login is performed through the website to which the client is embedded. I can't think of a way of passing an authentication token to it other than to completely rewrite everything so that the client handles the login.

Comment: That's the point and  you could focus on passing an authentication token from web to Unity 3D on client side.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 5/8/2020**

> Passing authentication token from `web` to `Unity 3D`

Since you have less detail about client, I take a example about Unity Web Player and browser communication.

**[Calling Unity web player content functions from the web page](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html)**

The Unity Web Player object has a function, `SendMessage()`, that can be called from a web page in order to call functions within Unity web player content. This function is very similar to the `GameObject.SendMessage` function in the Unity scripting API. When called from a web page you pass an object name, a function name and a single argument, and `SendMessage()` will call the given function in the given game object.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!--
//initializing the WebPlayer
var u = new UnityObject2();
u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "Example.unity3d");

function SaySomethingToUnity()
{
    u.getUnity().SendMessage("MyObject", "MyFunction", "Hello from a web page!");
}
-->
</script>
```

You can use to send `authentication token`.

---

> So, what I need to do is find a way to get current logged in user
> information inside a Web API where the API doesn't need to receive any
> tokens or other information to do it.

If we have a `API` to get `tokens` as you expect, then you access all APIs with this token. **Authentication** will be useless and system becomes unsafe. Because everyone can access with the magic `api`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I'm not sure it answers the question directly as I can't currently get the access token TO the unity project but it's given me an avenue of investigation. I'm guessing that, theoretically, I could generate a token upon login on the web page and, upon startup, the Unity project can try to retrieve this token.

Comment: That's right. Share with us when you have better solution.